# Applying Class to Items in a List

Tags: python

What I'm trying to do is allow any number of attributes to be supplied to a function. This function will handle creating a class based on those attributes. Then, I've got another function that will handle importing data from a text file, applying the generated class to each item, and adding it to a list. Below is what I have.

```
def create_class(attributes):
    class classObject:
        def __init__(self, **attributes):
            for attr in attributes.keys():
                self.__dict__[attr] = attributes[attr]

    return classObject

def file_to_list(file, attributes):
    classObject = create_class(attributes)

    with open(file, "r") as f:
        var = []

        for line in f.readlines():
            var.append(classObject(line))

    return var

data = file_to_list("file.txt", ["propA", "propB"])
```

The issue is with how I'm trying to add the item to the list. Normally, I wouldn't have any issue, but I believe the way in which I'm creating the class is causing issues with how I usually do it.

> File "file.py", line 17, in file_to_list
>       var.append(classObject(line))
>   TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How do I loop through each of the attributes of the class, so that I can set the value for each and add it to the list?

UPDATE:
Below is an example of what file.txt looks like.

```
1A,1B
2A,2B
3A,3B
```

Comment: What does a `line` look like?

Comment: classmethod to create class from string within the class could be the solution you are looking for.

Comment: Given that file, what do you expect your class to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your class generation is wrong. You appear to want to be able to do:

```
Cls = create_class(["some", "attributes", "go", "here"])
```

and end up with a class object that looks like:

```
class Cls(object):
    def __init__(self, some, attributes, go, here):
        self.some = some
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.go = go
        self.here = here
```

but what you're actually doing is creating a class that takes a dictionary, and gives that dictionary dot-syntax.

```
>>> obj = Cls({"different": "attributes", "go": "here"})
>>> obj.different
"attributes"
>>> obj.go
"here"
```

You can implement the former with:

```
def create_class(attributes: typing.List[str]):
    class gen_class(object):
        def __init__(self, *args):
            if len(args) != len(attributes):
                # how do you handle the case where the caller specifies fewer or more
                # arguments than the generated class expects? I would throw a...
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong number of arguments (expected {len(attributes)}, got {len(args)}.")
            for attr, value in zip(attributes, args):
                setattr(self, attr, value)
```

Then you should be able to use `csv.reader` to read in your file and instantiate those classes.

```
import csv

CSV_Cls = create_class(["propA", "propB"])

with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [CSV_Cls(*row) for row in reader]
```

---

However, it does seem that writing your own code generator to make that class is the wrong choice here. Why not used a `collections.namedtuple` instead?

```
from collections import namedtuple

CSV_Cls = namedtuple("CSV_Cls", "propA propB")

with open(file) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [CSV_Cls(*row) for row in reader]
```

This stdlib codegen is already written, known to work (and heavily tested) and won't accidentally introduce errors. The only reason to prefer a class is if you need to tightly-couple some behavior to the data, or if you need a mutable data structure

Comment: `namedtuple` does create a class though. But I'm still not sure if that's the kind of class the author wants.

Comment: @gilch yeah I allude to that in the text after the code block, but I should be more explicit.

Comment: I think a `namedtuple` would be a problem. The reason the `create_class` function was by itself was for cases when I want to add the attribute values one by one. I'd provide the attributes of the class to build the class, but not create any objects within it. As I determine those values, I'd add them to the class object. Once all values are determined, I add the class object to a list.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't seem to be working for me. I keep getting the following when using your 2nd and 3rd to last code blocks. 
`File "file.py", line 20, in <listcomp>`
`data = [CSV_Cls(*row) for row in reader]`
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

Comment: Nevermind. I see the issue. It seems to work the way I want. As far as the `namedtuple`, the code definitely seems cleaner for it. Unfortunately, I would need a mutable data structure. Thanks for the detailed explanation and code examples!

Answer (score 0):

First, why not use `type` for this instead? It's the default metaclass, i.e. a callable that creates class objects. The class dict will be the third argument, which makes it easy to create programmatically.

```
type(name, (), attributes)
```

(You probably don't need any base classes, but that's what the second argument is for.)

---

Second, your `__init__` doesn't appear to accept a str, which is the only thing you can get from `readlines()`. It takes only self (implied) and keyword arguments.

You could perhaps convert the `line` str to a dict (but that depends on what's in it), and then use the dict as your kwargs, like `classObject(**kwargs)`, but then there's probably no point in declaring it with stars in the `__init__` method in the first place.